# Get pk from previous URL

Tags: django

I would like to get the pk from the URL that was before, for example:

```
/instructor/1
/instructor/1/sex/2
```

The problem is that inn URL.py displays a new URL when sex is selected and I can't save the instructor's pk.

This is URL.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.InstructorListView.as_view(), name='instructor_list'),
    url(r'^instructor/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$',  views.SexoListView.as_view(), name='sexo_list'),
    url(r'^instructor/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/sexo/(?P<pk2>[\w-]+)$', views.RutinaListView.as_view(), name='rutina_list'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.InstructorDetailView.as_view(), name='instructor_detail'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rutinas.models import Instructor, Rutina, Sexo
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.


class InstructorListView(ListView):
    model = Instructor


class InstructorDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Instructor


class RutinaListView(ListView):
    model = Rutina

    # Filtro de rutinas deacuerdo a la seleccion de instructor y sexo

    def get_queryset(self):
        inst = Rutina.objects.filter(sexo=self.kwargs['pk2'], instructor=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return inst


class SexoListView(ListView):
    model = Sexo
```

For test I have the folowing in a sex_list template

```
<a href="{% url 'rutina_list' pk=1 pk2=sexo.pk %}">

            {{ sexo.genero }}
 </a>
```

i just what that pk is equal from the pk that was selected in instructor_list, but it displays a new webpage and pk is refreshed.

I want the pk from this URL:

```
url(r'^instructor/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$',  views.SexoListView.as_view(), name='sexo_list'),
```

Take it and past it in this URL:

```
url(r'^instructor/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/sexo/(?P<pk2>[\w-]+)$', views.RutinaListView.as_view(), name='rutina_list'),
```

Any ideas?

Comment: any idea of how to keep the pk from last url and dont refresh it as new? i know i have to apply some logic in views but i cant find something in documentation

Answer (score 0):

For the last url you can have

```
request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

in your view, that will give you the last url.

I think  that it is not what you are looking for, maybe you can give us some insights of what you want to do.

Comment: I want to keep the pk in url each time user redirects, something like category and subcategory